# setting date format on an excel form

Tags: date, format

I have created a form to enter a new line of data to the end of an excel table. When I open the form, I have created VBA code to enter the current date in this format.

18/05/2021

However, I'd like to be able to have the current date appear in this format on the form.

18th May 2021

My present line of code looks like this.

Supplier_Form.DateofInvoice = Format(Date, ddmmmmyyyy)

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try `Supplier_Form.DateofInvoice = Format(Date, ddmmmyyyy)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't make any difference. It's still displaying 18/05/2021. Also, I'd like a "th" after the "18".